# why sort_by_key function requires closure of type FnMut but not Fn

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust programming and was going through the Closures chapter of Rust book. In the book it's mentioned that `sort_by_key` function requires closure of type `FnMut`, but I was wondering if the `sort_by_key` function closure doesn't mutate the item that's been captured by the closure, why not make it `Fn` type?

Comment: This allows for more flexible code. Note that `FnMut` doesn't mutate it's arguments, but rather it's captured environment. So it accepts more closures than just `Fn`.

Comment: To expand on what Alexander said, obviously `FnOnce` can't work because `sort_by_key` needs to call the closure more than once. That leaves `FnMut` as the most flexible option.

Comment: @PitaJ OP asked why `Fn` won't work but your comment tells why `FnOnce` won't work which obviously won't work

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze can you share an example when you say `FnMut` doesn't mutate it's arguments, but rather it's captured environment. 

In other words, how does the closure of `sort_by_key` mutate it's capture environment?

Answer (score 1):

[`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) is a supertrait of [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html). That means any instance of `Fn` can be used where `FnMut` is expected.

To maybe help explain this, here I've extended an example from `FnMut`'s docs:

```
fn do_twice<F>(mut func: F)
where F: FnMut()
{
    func();
    func();
}

fn main() {
    let mut x: usize = 1;
    {
        let add_two_to_x = || x += 2;
        do_twice(add_two_to_x);
        let print_stuff = || println!("Awesome!");        
        do_twice(print_stuff);
    }
    println!("{x}");  
}
```

Note that in the above example, `add_two_to_x` requires `FnMut` and wouldn't work with `Fn`, whereas `print_stuff` works both ways.

So with `FnMut` you (as a *consumer*), have the *freedom* to implement a closure that can mutate its environment, although you're not obliged to do so. With `Fn` you would be just more restricted.

Comment: It is clear that `FnMut` is a superset of `Fn` but the closure of  `sort_by_key` doesn't seem to mutate it's environment which clearly means it doesn't need a `FnMut` at all

Comment: `sort_by_key` accepting `FnMut` means that, if you need to, you can pass in a closure that modifies that closure's captured environment.

Comment: I got your point. Thanks.

Comment: @PitaJ do you have an example where you would pass a closure that mutate captured values to `sort_by_key`? To me it looks like a code smell and would make more sense to prevent it, but maybe there are legit use cases that I didn't think of.